# XSD includes a XSD and in turn includes another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xsd, xsd.exe

Ok I don't know if the title is specific enough, but I'm having a problem here.

I have a XSD called 
"A"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="ATypeIn.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="A" type="ATypeIn"/>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see it includes this next XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="file:////C:/Users/aaaaa/Documents/GerarClasses/Types.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ATypeIn">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Apol">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="R" type="RType"/>
                        <xs:element name="NAp" type="NApType"/>
                        <xs:element name="Ut"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

For the XSD.Exe to generate the class it needs the 3rd XSD called "Types" which is included in the 2nd.

Problem is in here, this XSD "Types" has a lot of types.
and the class generated when I call "**xsd A.xsd /classes**"
Includes all these extra things:

Am I doing something wrong or it's supposed to be like this and I can't do anything about it?

Thanks,

If I didn't explain myself good enough, please do ask about it and I will try to explain better.

PS: Obviously I changed the names in the code, so if there is any "mistake" it's for this reason.

Comment: No, that sounds about right to me. Note that xsd.exe is not the most sophisticated tool in the world (IMHO).

Comment: What does sound about right? The situation should happen like this? or the XSD files are ok and you don'e know what could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds about right that xsd.exe would give you the whole elephant even though all you wanted was the trunk ;)